# CSS3 Animations on hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to do something like this website [here](http://mariusn.com/themes/reales/) the gallery section near the bottom, can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

I have tried looking at the css but getting no where.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful to you:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/

Idea is the same, you just need to modify your effects.

Your example is linking to SVG file, where is defined blur effect.

```
<filter id="blur">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10">
</filter>
```

You can read more about this technique here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter